Change console icon on taskbar
I don't want to change the shortcut icon:
How To Add An Icon Of My Own To A Python Program
I want to change the console (cmd) icon that runs a python script:
Is there a way to change the console Icon at runtime
How do you change the windows console icon in python code?
However, it requires the window handle of the console:
Getting the instance handle of a window in python (ctypes)
Get position of console window in python
but the returned handle is for some small PseudoConsoleWindow rather than the real one.

You can experiment with
import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui, win32con, win32process
import psutil

img = r'c:\prog\icons\timer.ico'

def get_hwnds_for_pid( pid ):
    def callback( hwnd, hwnds ):
        found_pid = -1
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
            _, found_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        if found_pid == pid:
            hwnds.append( hwnd )
        return True
    
    hwnds = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, hwnds)
    return hwnds

if 0:
    pid = psutil.Process().pid
    print( 'pid', pid )
    
    pid = psutil.Process().ppid()
    print( 'ppid', pid )
    
    hwnds = get_hwnds_for_pid( pid )
    hwnd = hwnds[0]
else:
    hwnd = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()

print( hex(hwnd) )

win32console.SetConsoleTitle( 'ha1' ) # works as long as the script is running

win32gui.SetWindowText( hwnd, 'ha2' ) # doesn't work

icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
hicon = win32gui.LoadImage( None, img, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags )

# doesn't work
win32gui.SendMessage( hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_SMALL, hicon )
win32gui.SendMessage( hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_BIG, hicon )

input()

Find the window with spyxx.exe.

You should share the code you have that gets the handle to the PseudoConsoleWindow and let us know what type of terminal you are running your console in? Windows Console Host or Windows Terminal? How do you intend to change the icon? By sending a WM_SETICON?

As the links suggest: get a handle with GetConsoleWindow(), then send to it WM_SETICON. It's a standard cmd (WindowsTerminal.exe).

import win32api
import win32console
import win32gui, win32con, win32process
from ctypes import *
import time

user32 = windll.user32
EnumWindowsProc = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int)

img = r'c:\prog\icons\timer.ico'

def get_handle( title, classname ):
    hwnds = []
    def EnumCB(hwnd, lparam, title = title, classname = classname, hwnds = hwnds):
        title2 = c_buffer(b' ' * 256)
        user32.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title2, 255)
        title2 = title2.value.decode('UTF-8')
        
        classname2 = c_buffer(b' ' * 256)
        user32.GetClassNameA(hwnd, classname2, 255)
        classname2 = classname2.value.decode('UTF-8')
        
        if title in title2 and ( classname is None or classname2 == classname ):
            hwnds.append(hwnd)
        return True

    user32.EnumWindows( EnumWindowsProc( EnumCB ), 0 )
    return hwnds

if 0:
    hwnd = win32console.GetConsoleWindow() # dummy PseudoConsoleWindow 
    print( hex(hwnd) )

# give it a unique title to locate the real window
unique_title = '_unique123_'
win32console.SetConsoleTitle( unique_title ) # resets when the script ends

while 1:
    time.sleep( 0.1 ) # wait for the title to change
    hwnds = get_handle( unique_title, 'CASCADIA_HOSTING_WINDOW_CLASS' )
    if hwnds:
        hwnd = hwnds[0]
        break
print( hex(hwnd) )

# change title
title = 'timer'
win32gui.SetWindowText( hwnd, title )
win32console.SetConsoleTitle( title ) # change the tab title

# change icon
icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
hicon = win32gui.LoadImage( None, img, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags )
win32gui.SendMessage( hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_SMALL, hicon )
win32gui.SendMessage( hwnd, win32con.WM_SETICON, win32con.ICON_BIG, hicon )

input()


Interestingly, if you create a shortcut to the python script with a property
Run: Minimized

the console will get the shortcut's icon and caption. It's not hosted in a terminal as a tab anymore, but the python process owns the window.
